# One word to denote "A noun that conveys wrong meaning" or misleads

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose I'm building a website and I want to have a page to help the user know about the website: the apt title would be **Help**,  but I've named it **About**.
(Normally **About** pages tell us about the author / company /reason for the existence of that website, but I've used the term **Contact** here.)

What is the term for this? (I once came across the word, googled, and found the meaning. But I have now forgotten the word.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Anything that can be misunderstood will be misunderstood.'

But you may be thinking of **misnomer**, one of whose senses applies.